# Transposing and Concatenating strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I transpose and concatenate a pandas dataframe without using a for loop?

Here is the input data:

```
input_data =  pandas.DataFrame({'a': ['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'food', 'food', 'food', 'food'],
                      'b': ['banana', '', 'apple', 'rice', '', 'yam', 'chicken']})
```

Resulting output should look like this:

```
result = pandas.DataFrame({'a': ['fruit', 'food'],
                      'b': ['banana  apple', 'rice  yam  chicken']})
```

Here is my for loop solution:

```
stuff_list = input_data.a.drop_duplicates().tolist()
result = pandas.DataFrame()

for s in stuff_list:
    step1 = input_data[input_data.a == s]
    step2 = ' '.join(step1.b.tolist())
    step3 = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[s], 'b':[step2]})
    result = result.append(step3)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to group by column `a` and apply a string join to column `b`:

```
(input_data.groupby('a', sort=False)['b']
           .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
           .reset_index())

       a                  b
0  fruit      banana  apple
1   food  rice  yam chicken
```

Answer (score 2):

More like `agg`

```
df.groupby('a',sort=False,as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
Out[539]: 
       a                  b
0  fruit      banana  apple
1   food  rice  yam chicken
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby`:

```
>>> input_data.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
       a                  b
0   food  rice  yam chicken
1  fruit      banana  apple
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `agg`, you don't need `lambda`

```
input_data.groupby('a', sort=False).b.agg(' '.join).reset_index()

Out[2266]:
       a                  b
0  fruit      banana  apple
1   food  rice  yam chicken
```